# Type ' { } ' is not assignable to type ' ReactNode '

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I'm getting an error in below code snippet.
I'm working on code that was originally written by another developer.
I'm trying to run the app and I'm getting a bug.

Anyone knows how I can fix it ?

Code

```
const ConditionalLink = (props: ConditionalLinkProps) =>
    !!props.condition && props.to ? (
        <Link to={props.to} className="Card__Link">
            {props.children}
        </Link>
    ) : (
        <>{props.children}</>
    );

interface Props {
    headline: string;
    preamble?: string;
    image?: ImageObject;
    guid: string;
    link?: string;
    status?: string;
    startDate?: DateObject;
    endDate?: DateObject;
}
```

Error

```
Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("d:/Development/Work Projects/ssu/ssuplus.frontend/node_modules/@types/testing-library__react/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1376, 9): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LinkProps<unknown> & RefAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>'

Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.  TS2322

    15 |        !!props.condition && props.to ? (
    16 |                <Link to={props.to} className="Card__Link">
  > 17 |                        {props.children}
       |                        ^
    18 |                </Link>
    19 |        ) : (
    20 |                <>{props.children}</>
```

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@datapunt/matomo-tracker-react": "^0.5.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/classnames": "^2.2.10",
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.34",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.31",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.6",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.5",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "@types/react-select": "^4.0.7",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.4",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.0.1",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "npm-normalize-package-bin": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-icalendar-link": "^3.0.2",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "react-select": "^4.0.2",
    "react-slick": "^0.25.2",
    "serve": "^11.3.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
    },
```

"devDependencies": {
"@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
"sass": "^1.56.0",
"ticks-to-date": "^1.0.3"
}

Comment: Seems to me like different versions of `@types/react`. Can you share your `package.json` `dependencies` and `devDependencies`?

Comment: "devDependencies": { "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0", "sass": "^1.56.0", "ticks-to-date": "^1.0.3" }

Comment: It might be that another conflicting version of `@types/react` exists due to shadow dependency. If you happen to use yarn instead of npm, `yarn why @types/react` may help you identify which versions are installed. If there are multiple versions, [this](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) guide tells how to lock a package to one single version.

Comment: I run - ```yarn why @types/react``` - and I got - ```Found "@types/react@16.14.34"``` - ```Found "@types/react-router#@types/react@18.0.25"```

Comment: The error message shows the incompatibility between `@types/react.ReactNode` versions 16 and 18. But in your case, you specify version 16 explicitly, and as far as I can see, most of your other types that depend on `@types/react` accept any version (`*`), so if the dependency management works right, it should use the same version as you explicitly requested, instead of using a more recent one. However, it seems that yarn may resolve versions slightly differently from npm. If possible, try a fresh install, and another package manager.